# Is there an algorithm to test for an acyclic undirected graph, using edge data, not node data (e.g. adjacency matrix)

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given an adjacency matrix or other data based on the nodes, there are many algorithms for determining whether the graph is acyclic (e.g. row reduction or leaf trimming).

If I have only a set of edges (e.g. ${(a,b), (b,c), (d,b)}$), I could obviously convert that into an adjacency matrix and proceed from there.

I'm wondering if there is a good algorithm that works directly with the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a disjoint set (union-find) data structure and iterate through the edges one by one. For each edge $(u, v)$, if the two vertices already belong to the same subset, then the graph is not acyclic. Otherwise, you merge the subset containing $u$ with the subset containing $v$. If all edges are added successfully, the graph is acyclic.

This runs in $O(E\alpha(V))$, where $V$ is the number of vertices, $E$ is the number of edges and $\alpha$ is the inverse Ackermann function.

In principle, however, I don't think that this is any faster than iterating through the edges to build an adjacency list and then use that for determining if the graph is acyclic.

Comment: "*I don't think that this is any faster than …*".  Right. Some people have trouble relating algebraic manipulation to "reality".  I wanted a graphical rather than an algebraic solution. And this is it.  Thanks.